# Display NoRowMessage when the column value is a blank string

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a SSRS report, in which i have a dataset in which some of the rows are completely empty strings. And the report runs on a selected parameter value. When I select a parameter value and if all the column values for that parameter value is an empty string, then the result is displayed as an empty table.

But instead I would like to display it with an error message as "No data available for the selected parameter".

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the grids' NoDataRows message to be this.

Answer (score 0):

NoRowMessage don't work for an empty table I guess.

Instead what I did was, I added an extra row above the empty row in the table(i.e., in between the column headings row and the details row) that is being displayed when the selected parameter doesn't have any data. And I merged all the cells, then wrote whatever error message that I wanted to display. Then I change row visibility of that row to

Show or Hide based on an expression

and the expression I used is as follows

-- This expression is to hide the row -- True --> Hide, False --> Show

=IIF(Fields!Field.Value <> " ", True, False) -- In case if the row you want to hide contains a field value that is empty.

Then change the row visibility of the details row to

=IIF(Fields!Field.Value = " ", True, False)

The first expressions displays the row when the table is empty. And the second expression displays the details rows when the table returns any values.

Hope this helps to someone who faces the same issue. If anybody has anymore doubts regarding this they can reply me back here.

Thank you.